# How can I create linked tags from a comma separated list value in Stacey App?

Tags: php, arrays, list, twig

I'd like to have tags/categories per project in Stacey like 'design', 'photography', 'illustration' etc, and have each be linked to their respective categories.

For example, my project.yml file reads:

```
title: Example Person's Logo
date: February 2014
client: Example Person
category: Logo, Digital,
content: +++
Branding for Example Person.
+++
```

So, when in Stacey (v3) when in my project.html template I put `{{ page.category }}` it outputs `Logo, Digital,`, which is not what I'd like. It'd be fine if I wanted just text, but I don't.

What I'd like is to grab the comma separated value (whether or not the last item has a comma), and turn it into this:

```
<a href="/category/logo/">Logo</a>
<a href="/category/digital/">Digital</a>
```

I've done some searching, and using the TWIG templating engine I'm unsure how this could be achieved without backreferences like in PHP. I'm told that in PHP the solution would be like this:

```
<?php echo preg_replace(
    "#([^,\s]+)#is",
    "<a href='/tags/$1'>$1</a>",
    $row['tags']);
?>
```

However I don't know how I could turn the comma separated list from 'category:' to an array, then strip the array of commas, and put the link tags around each while linking to the category in the href.

I've also tried using the above PHP as a partial, however dynamic code won't work in Stacey due to the caching, and it can't be referenced from outside the /partials/ folder.

I'm rather confused by all of this, any help would be hugely appreciated.

Note: Stacey doesn't have the latest version of Twig which has filters like 'split'.

Comment: For the record, the capturing parentheses, the `i` modifier, and the `s` modifier don't add any benefit to your pattern (they are uselessly bloating your pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Twig's [`split`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) filter, then check if the element is not empty.

```
{% set categories = page.category|split(',') %}


{% for category in categories %}
    {% if category is not empty %}
        <a href="/category/{{ category|lower }}/">{{ category }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Since Stacy is [still using version 1.4 at time of writing](https://github.com/kolber/stacey/blob/6b1f765cf650ef18507d54e18a773dd9bc4fc091/app/parsers/Twig/Environment.php#L20) and that this filter was added to Twig in 1.10, you'll need to add this filter yourself.

In `extensions/twig-extensions.inc.php`, you can add a new filter to the extension's `getFilters` array

```
public function getFilters() {
    # custom twig filters
    return array(

      //... other filters here ...

      'split' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'split'),
    );
}
```

Then after the `public function getFunctions()` method add this method

```
/**
 * Custom filter method
 *
 * @param string $str
 * @param string $delimiter
 * @return string[]
 */
public function split($str, $delimiter) {
  return explode($delimiter, $str);
}
```

Comment: Cheers Adam! Though the split filter isn't included in Stacey oddly. I'll dig around and try to update Twig for Stacey and try getting split working. Your code looks like it'd work to me, I'll see if I get far with it.

Otherwise, I've mused about using replace or trim somehow, no clue how to do that for this specific example.

Comment: @LouisBullock The split filter is actually part of Twig, but on the docs it says _The split filter was added in Twig 1.10.3._ However checking the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/kolber/stacey/blob/master/app/parsers/Twig/Environment.php#L20) confirms v1.4 release candidate of Twig is being used. If you could upgrade Twig, it would be ideal. Are you familiar with using Composer to install packages?

Comment: The alternative is to add a new split filter to Twig yourself. I'll expand my answer to show you how

Comment: Ah brilliant! I'm not familiar with any of this unfortunately, it seems very new to me :) Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: @LouisBullock damn, looks like the `Twig_SimpleFilter` class was also added after version 1.4... I'll update my answer again

Comment: @LouisBullock Ok updated, and I tested it too, it works.

Comment: Fantastic, it works! Thanks Adam, much appreciated! Next, I gotta figure out how to display projects tagged with a certain category in their respective category page, e.g. all design projects on /category/design/.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Extended Adam's code to this

```
{% set categories = page.category|replace({', ' : ','})|split(',') %}
    {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category is not empty %}
            <dd><a href="/category/{{ category|lower|replace({' ' : '-', ',' : ''}) }}/">{{ category }}</a></dd>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

What this does is turn the spaces in the urls to hyphens to make them cleaner, then gets rid of spaces after commas, separates the words between the commas, then removes any excess commas. I would've liked to use the 'trim' filter, but like 'split' it isn't available.