# How to match array values across arrays?

Tags: arrays, twig

Well, its 8 years or so ago, and I'm still trying to figure some of this out ([How can I create linked tags from a comma separated list value in Stacey App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313386/how-can-i-create-linked-tags-from-a-comma-separated-list-value-in-stacey-app)), but I'm making some better progress.

I have a few `project.yml` files in Stacey App/CMS:

1.
`/projects/design-project/project.yml`

```
title: Design project
category: [Logo, Design]
content: +++
This is a design project.
+++
```

2. 

`/projects/illustration-project/project.yml`

```
title: Illustration project
category: [Illustration, Animation, Handmade, Design]
content: +++
This is an illustration project.
+++
```

3. 

`/projects/video-project/project.yml`

```
title: Video project.
category: [Video, Animation, Illustration]
content: +++
This is a video project.
+++
```

What I'd like is on a new template page, let's call it `indvidual-category.html`, it will look through all the available projects (these three for example, and display something like this:

**Design:** Design project, Illustration project
**Logo:** Design project
**Illustration:** Illustration project, Video project
**Animation:** Illustration project, Video project
**Handmade:** Illustration project
**Video:** Video project

So, I need Twig templating code to first look at the `category:` arrays in each `project.yml`, look through the array as individual items, check to see if in this example `Design project` has a match of any category array items with `Illustration project` and vice versa.

And, if that is the case, output the categories listed on the `individual-category.yml` page, showing each category across all the possible categories in all the `project.yml` files that exist, and show any projects that have matching categories in the same list.

What I'm aiming for is for you to be able to go to say `/projects/category/design/individual-category.yml` and all the projects that have `Design` in the `category:` key part of their `project.yml` will show up listed there.

I will have the correct hyperlinks and relevant thumbnails to each from there.

Is *matching* the right way to go here or is there some other way of *comparing* across arrays that I'm missing? I don't want to have to list each match individually, its more the case of if there is a match for that individual category, put all of that individual category together in one spot and display that.

Potentially this could turn into grabbing those matches and putting them into an array on the side that could be useful later?

A bit of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why you don't do this in a controller? Also I'm not even sure how `twig` itself would be able to access all those `yaml` files on it's own

Comment: Hi @DarkBee, I am using Stacey App/CMS, which uses Twig for templating, I'm trying match matching items of these arrays, to output those matches on individual category pages. Would you happen to be familiar with Twig? :)

Comment: Merging/grouping items in `twig` is very "messy". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401743/reorganize-array-in-twig)